# Raspberry Pi (compute module) stopped turning on (no LED's turning on either)

Tags: power

I have been using a raspberry pi all morning, and now suddenly when I plug in the power supply which is 12V, no LED's turn on, and the board does not power on. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which Pi is this? I don't know of a Pi except the Compute Module which would survive being powered at 12V .....

Comment: @PhilB. it is the compute module

Comment: Ok. Start with isolating the issue. Is there power on the outlet (who knows maybe you blew a fuse?)? If yes, does the supply still provide the right voltage (check with a multimeter)? Can you exchange the power supply for another one and does it work then? Do you have another board into which you can plug the Compute module and does it work then? Can you use a multimeter on the supply pins on the board to see if it gets power? There might have been a power surge that hit the supply and it has temporarily shut off - if you let it cool down for a while it might work again. Let us know ....

Comment: @PhilB. power supply works, just tried it with another board and the board powered on, unlike this one. This seems to be a hardware issue, still checking though...